# Only One Column Shows Up in Windows Form Chart from Database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Despite there is 3 rows in database, only one column shows up in chart. And It always shows First PartyName and biggest Vote value.

```
    OleDbConnection AConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Windows\\Temp\\DATABASE\\secim.accdb");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
        {
            series.Points.Clear();
        }

        AConnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Sonuc", AConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["VOTES"].Points.AddXY(reader["PartyName"].ToString(), reader["Vote"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        AConnection.Close();
    }
```

Here is the images of Database and the Result:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv6Mw.png) --  [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a59DD.png)

All rows in database must show up in chart.

Comment: Comment out the line command.ExecuteNonQuery(); Your command query does not have any Insert, Update or Delete.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I don't know if you said that for solution or to inform but it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you try this instead of looping through?chart1.Series["VOTES"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "PartyName", reader, "Vote");

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Also, can you close the reader after read is done? reader.Close()has to be explicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

1. `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` is useless
2. You should always close all the connections to the database. You can do it either by explicitly saying `.Close()` or with `using` statement like this:

`using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Sonuc", AConnection))`

`using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {  }`

3. You can log each iteration to console using `Debug.WriteLine();` to check if it loads each row correctly. If it does, the last thing to consider is to invalidate the chart itself using `chart1.Invalidate();` at the very end.
4. I recommend you to split the variables to make it more readable for further generations

   `string partyName = reader["PartyName"].ToString();`

   `double votes = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Vote"]);`

   `chart1.Series["VOTES"].Points.AddXY(partyName, votes);`